# location.reload() takes too long, how to make it reload immediately?

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I have a web app which needs to be reloaded if a certain button is pressed.
The refreshing of the page supposed to happen then moment I press the button and then I do some computation. The problem is that even though the reload is called before the computation, the computation happens before the reload.

Is there any way to resolve this?

```
eel.expose(ReloadPage);
function ReloadPage()
{
  location.reload();
}


    def LoadButtonFunc(self):
        chosen_load_file = filedialog.askopenfile(title="Load testing session" ,mode = 'r',filetypes = [("Pashosh file", "*.psh")])
        if chosen_load_file == None:
            return
        
        # reset all data before loading
        eel.ReloadPage()                    
        self.DB.clear()                     
        self.global_row_index = 0
        self.input_dir = None

        [self.DB, self.input_dir] = json.load(chosen_load_file)
        self.WorkDirButtonFunc(self.input_dir)

        for elem in self.DB:
            eel.BuildRowUI(self.matlabTests_list, self.global_row_index, elem)
            self.UpdateRowIndex()
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  **Why** do you want to reload your page before some process happens? Eel basically works using websockets, so given the async nature of JavaScript and the page reload there's no way to guarantee the reload finishing before your Python code.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I also tried sleep for 10 seconds after the reload but still had the same output. There is no way that the reload took more then 10 seconds.